# Determine the number of trials

Tags: combinatorics

*Based on Fivethirtyeight's riddler challenge*

Suppose a team has $p$ probability of winning a game against an opponent.  This probability does not change, and is the same or every opponent.  What is the expected number of games required to win a best of 7 series?

This is a little tricky.  Four wins are required to win the series, but they can come in different permutations.  I know the negative binomial can be used to determine the probability of $n$ trials for $r$ successes, but it may include cases which are not allowed (for instance WWWLWLL.  After the first four wins, the series is over).

Is there a way to model this sort of process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four possible outcomes to win a best of seven. In order to win in $n$ games, we have to loose $n-4$ out of $n-1$ first games, and win the $n^{th}$ one. As such, we can distinguish the following scenarios:

1. Win in four games with probability $p^4$
2. Win in five games with probability ${4 \choose 1} p^4 (1-p)$
3. Win in six games with probability ${5 \choose 2} p^4 (1-p)^2$
4. Win in seven games with probability ${6 \choose 3} p^4 (1-p)^3$

Since the sample space is restricted to wins only, theses probabilities must be normalized. As such, the expected number of games equals:

$$\frac{4 p^4 + 5 {4 \choose 1} p^4 (1-p) + 6 {5 \choose 2} p^4 (1-p)^2 + 7 {6 \choose 3} p^4 (1-p)^3}{p^4 + {4 \choose 1} p^4 (1-p) + {5 \choose 2} p^4 (1-p)^2 + {6 \choose 3} p^4 (1-p)^3}$$

Comment: How do did you go about choosing the binomial coefficients?  That is the part that really gets me.

Comment: @DemetriP When $n$ is the total number of games needed to win the best of seven, you can choose $n-4$ out of $n-1$ games which are lost, while the others need to be won. For instance, to win in five games, we can loose the first one (probability $(1-p) \times p \times p \times p \times p$), the second one (probability $p \times (1-p) \times p \times p \times p$), the third one (probability $p \times p \times (1-p) \times p \times p$) or the fourth one (probability $p \times p \times p \times (1-p) \times p$). Therefore, we need to multiply $p^4(1-p)^{n-4}$ by ${n-1 \choose n-4}$.